# Searching a large csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv reference data file of around 1m rows. I have a csv data file of 3m rows. I need to perform a reference data lookup for each of the 3m rows into the 1m row csv file.

For various reasons I am constrained to python and cvs. I have tried to have the 1m row table in a panda in memory but the whole thing is very slow.

Can someone recommend an alternative approach?

Comment: More code and sample data please

Comment: "various reasons" sounds like homework. You can do a line read. It would be slow but it would work, and time wasn't listed under constraints.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps I wasn’t clear enough. Sorry. So I am doing a line read. I four a few functions to execute on each line. All of them except the reference data lookup run really fast. The reference data lookup is to retrieve 1 value from the panda.

Comment: The code would be helpful. You only need to find one row in the bunch?

Comment: dump the csv into a sqlite db and then just query as needed

Comment: I will post some code snippets when I am on my computer rather than my smartphone.

Comment: Yes. I only need to find 1 row in the 1m row csv. For each of the 3m data rows.

Comment: To clarify my question, is there only one row being matched in total? Or do each of the 1m rows need to find a home in the 3m row dataset?

Comment: Each row in the 3m file has a ‘foreign key’ relationship to the 1m row file. I like the idea of sql lite. Is it performant on creating a 1m row table and some indices?

Comment: This is a clear candidate for a data base application.  Put each of the two data sets into a DB, describe the foreign key mapping, and invoke the "merge" or "link" command.

Comment: Sadly any dB other than SQLite is not an option.

Comment: @SuperStew I did as you said and it is flying. 3m rows in 30 mins. If you put that up as an answer I will accept it to close this question. Thanks.

Comment: @user2302244 well if you insist :), glad its working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, a good solution to this type of thing would be to dump the CSV into a sqlite db and the just query as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea.

```
import csv
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("C:\\your_path_here\\test.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)
```